# How to calculate webpage transferred size programmatically? Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I want to calculate this value(check screenshot) programmatically.

I've tried Performance API's methods but the values are different. I don't want to attach a debugger to a webpage or adding a custom dev panel

[image]

```js
const transferSize = performance.getEntriesByType('resource').map(item => item.transferSize).reduce((total, item) => total + item);
const encodedBodySize= performance.getEntriesByType('resource').map(item => item.encodedBodySize).reduce((total, item) => total + item);
const decodedBodySize= performance.getEntriesByType('resource').map(item => item.decodedBodySize).reduce((total, item) => total + item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks correct to me. But, there was one thing that looked weird in below code:

```
performance.getEntriesByType('resource').length;
```

The above gives me the length of request calls for only resource type, but what you actually might need is the transferSize for all the network calls and not only of resource type. This must be the reason that the transferSize is not getting matched.

I tried the following code and it seemed to me:

```
var count = 0;
performance.getEntries().map(item => item.transferSize).forEach(size => {
if (typeof size == 'number') {
count = count + size;
}
});
```

This code returns me the transferSize for all the network calls, and the length of request calls also matches up. I have provided a `typeof` check, as there were some `undefined` transfer sizes

Comment: This also gives wrong values, I tried it on google and it is  showing 324473

Comment: Right. Some URL's are not giving proper length as well as the transfer size is also different. In some cases, it returns correct size. There might be something which we might not be considering. Lets wait for another answer.

Comment: ok lets see, btw thank you for correcting me :)

Comment: I've noticed one thing. Some  resources having 
initiatorType ="link" and 
initiatorType: "script" 

have transferSize= 0

Maybe the browser is counting their sizes also, but Peforomance API is  not giving their transferSize

Comment: It might be considering some other property for the transfer size having 0.

Comment: According to MDN  " If the resource is fetched from a local cache, or if it is a cross-origin resource, this property returns zero". I just logged all resources having this property 0, their URLs are cross-origin, but I manually calculate the transfer size of those links and sum up the values but output is wrong